# get_the_post_thumbnail() not working in a page template

Tags: wordpress, loops, include, thumbnails

The following code is placed inside an include file named latest-web.php :

```
<?php
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '8', 'category_name' => 'web-reference' );
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                        $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail();
                        $poveznica = get_field('link-projekta');
                        echo '<figure class="effect-winston">
                        ' . $featured_image . '
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . $recent["post_title"] . '</a></h2>
                            <p>
                                <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list"></i></a>
                                <a href="' . $poveznica . '" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-link"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>';
                    }
                    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

When including the file in index.html, it works flawlessly, but when including it in the page template, there is a problem. The code pulls all the info correctly. However, the image/thumbnail is not displayed at all. There is no img tag when inspecting from the browser. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried 
$featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]);

Comment: Hello, I have just tried it. When using your code, it doesn't work both on index and page template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, added recent id in thumbnail function.

```
<?php
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '8');
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                        $featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]);
                        $poveznica = get_field('link-projekta');
                        echo '<figure class="effect-winston">
                        ' . $featured_image . '
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . $recent["post_title"] . '</a></h2>
                            <p>
                                <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list"></i></a>
                                <a href="' . $poveznica . '" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-link"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>';
                    }
                    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: I must have made a mistake when trying it out the first time. Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the some time get_the_post_thumbnail() is not working until you pass the ID of post so in your case foeach loop so yo have to pass recent[ID] in get_the_post_thumbnail(),
so it's look like get_the_post_thumbnail(recent['ID']), and you done mate